# Ideal Objects: Is there such a thing as an Ideal Functionality with persistent memory?

Tags: multiparty-computation

In general, proofs of security for secure Multiparty Computation are based on Ideal Functionalities. For instance, see Definition 4.1 of [this Simulator tutorial](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf).

However, in a regular program in an object-oriented programming language, one deals not only with functions but with objects. Objects have functions, but also have some persistent memory.

It is possible to implement MPC objects. For instance [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-662-45608-8_27.pdf) implements oblivious (i.e. MPC) arrays, dictionaries and priority queues. In these memory is persisted in a secret-shared manner which is accessed for future queries.

However, it seems that formalism for these objects is lacking. Intuitively, an MPC object should not reveal any more information than calls to some Ideal Object, which returns only (secret-shares of) the results to (secret-shared) queries on the object. Describing an Ideal Object as a sequences of calls to Ideal Functionalities does not work, because in-between the parties get correlated shares of data-structures, and so the functionalities have to be defined in reference to whatever data structure is used, rather than just in terms of the desired properties of the object.

Is there any formalism in the literature for how to prove security of MPC objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is called **reactive**. A reactive functionality receives inputs and gives outputs over many rounds. In between rounds, it maintains a private internal state. The usual MPC frameworks like UC already support reactive functionalities, so there is nothing special you need to do to use them.

Examples:

- The *commitment* functionality is a standard primitive, and often called a "cryptographic locked box." In the *commit phase*, the sender provides a secret value to the functionality; in a later *reveal phase*, the sender allows the receiver to learn that secret value. Between these phases the functionality stores the secret value in its private state.
- The *arithmetic black box* (ABB) was introduced [here](https://iacr.org/archive/crypto2003/27290247/27290247.pdf). It is a useful abstraction for defining many MPC protocols. The ABB functionality allows parties to initialize variables and then blindly perform operations on them. The functionality is usually achieved by using some kind of secret sharing protocol, but the functionality's specification only talks about an ideal collection of variables and operations on them.